# Ambiguous overloaded call to 'foo'. Bug in D6? Scope of bug?

Tags: delphi

I am getting a compile error 'Ambiguous overloaded call to ...' for no apparent reason. This [seems to be a bug in Delphi 6](http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-pascal-delphi-misc/137788-ambiguous-overloaded-call.html). What is the scope of this bug? Does it only affect functions with 'array of' parameters? Has it been fixed in newer versions of Delphi?

```
// This is a simple example to produce the compiler error, not a real program.
function ShowInt(const a: array of string; const i: longint): string;  overload;
begin
  Result := 'Longint ' + IntToStr(i);
end;

function ShowInt(const a: array of string; const i: int64): string;  overload;
begin
  Result := 'Int64 ' + IntToStr(i);
end;

procedure Test;
var
  i64: int64;
  ilong: longint;
begin
  ShowInt([], i64  ); // In D6 why does this line compile OK, but next line gives
  ShowInt([], ilong); // compile error: Ambiguous overloaded call to 'ShowInt'.
end;                  // And if the array parameter is removed it compiles OK.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a compiler bug and it has been fixed in D2009.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Would you happen to have a QC number? I am interested in reading it.

Comment: Report No: 56504 (RAID: 257008)          Status: Closed
"Ambiguous overloaded call" with Integer/Int64/UInt64 overloaded versions
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=56504

Comment: @Uwe It might be the same bug. I am not sure from that information. Their bug exhibits without an 'array of' parameter and mine does not. I have just experimented with different types of integer such as Cardinal, Byte, Word, Longword and Longint and I always seem to get the message on the function with the shorter type. Maybe that will help diagnose it.

Comment: @soid - In general one could say that many of the 'overload'ing issues seems to be resolved in D2009. Like, [11565](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=11565), [47461](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=47461), [56503](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=56503). Particularly the 47461 one seems to be relevant with your question, see the comments to the report.

Comment: @Sertac Yes, that one looks very close. Maybe I could ask that somebody with a copy of D2009 or above copy and paste my code just to confirm it is fixed.

Comment: @soid - I thought Uwe confirmed, but maybe not.. I can confirm D2007 displays the bug.

Comment: D2007 latest compiler 11.0.2963.11001 (April 2008 Hotfix) has the issue; D2009 earliest compiler 12.0.3170.16989 (RTM) doesn't have the issue

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if it's a bug or by design but I think you will get into trouble trying to overload based on different integer types. For example, the compiler can't distinguish between integer literals, e.g. is 1 an integer or an int64 or a byte or a word or a shortint etc. It could be any of those. Whilst the compiler can make rules to distinguish, I don't think they would be intuitive.

In your example, when you pass an integer variable, either routine could be called.

I prefer to keep overloading to a minimum which you can do here by having just an int64 version.

Comment: Good point. For some reason I didn't think of that. I'll distinguish them in the function name if I need two versions.

Comment: But I am not convinced it could be by design because it compiles OK if the array parameter is removed from the functions and the calls. This ought to give an error too if it is by design.

Comment: That's a good point, but perhaps the behaviour without the array param is the bug! Did you look in the docs for integer overloading rules?

Comment: @David I admit I didn't, but I have now. The Object Pascal Language Guide page titled 'Overloading procedures and functions' in my D6 help system seems to say it will work as I would expect: 'In these cases, when it is possible to do so without ambiguity, the compiler invokes the routine whose parameters are of the type with the smallest range that accommodates the actual parameters in the call.'

Comment: even that leaves room for ambiguity. Consider 257. Does that result in a call to the shortint or the word version? I suppose it should be an error which fits with the documentation I guess. All the same, I stand firmly behind my advice not to rely on such overloading rules.

Comment: While I think that overloading is often unnecessary and prefer functions with different names, an Int64 version of a function could be rather inefficient compared to a Longint version. -- But we are talking about D6 here, and many bugs have been fixed since then, especially WRT overloading. FWIW, 257 doesn't fit in a Shortint. Did you mean Smallint?

Comment: @rudy yes, which ever one is 16 bit, I can never remember which way round those types are, I never use them.